# Подключение к sqlite3

Tags: sqlite3, php

Добрый вечер. В конец запутался в попытке подключиться к базе sqlite... Прошу помочь мне. Обьясните мне на пальцах, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы работало подключение к sqlite в php 5.3.10-1. Перечитал огромную кучу формумов, в результате мозг просто закипел от всяких советов подобных этим:

> -воспользуйтесь командой установки PEAR: "pear install sqlite".
>
> -Начиная с версии PHP 5.4, расширение SQLite доступно только через PECL.

Очень надеюсь на вашу помошь. Ещё раз слёзно прошу обьяснить мне всё на пальцах, я буду вам очень благодарен.

Comment: Если sqlite уже установлен (можно глянуть через phpinfo())
то подключтся к базе можно так

    $db= new PDO("sqlite:base.sqlite");//base.sqlite - путь до файла базы

http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: а какая ОС? если *nix и php установлен через менеджер пакетов, то можно этим же менеджером доустановить и расширение

Comment: Таким образом?

1. Устанавливаем пакеты sqlite3 и libsqlite3-dev:

sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev

2. Устанавливаем gem sqlite3-ruby:

sudo apt-get install sqlite3-ruby

Comment: @istimbi, gem и sqlite3-ruby вам в php не потребуются. На ubuntu найти нужный пакет можно так:

    sudo apt-cache search sqlite | grep php

В списке увидите что-то типа

    php5-sqlite - Модуль SQLite для php5

Вот его и установите

    sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @istimbi, удалось подключиться?

Comment: Да удалось. Ещё раз спасибо вам. Правда у меня возникли новые вопросы... Как я понял у sqlite3 синтаксис команд отличается от предыдущих версий? Вот к примеру http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sqlite.php все описанные там команды не работают у меня(sqlite3) зато работает код описанный на  http://www.php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3.open.php Если вам не сложно дайте ссылку на документацию на sqlite3 на русском языке.

Comment: К примеру мне понятен код
<?php
$dbhandle = sqlite_open('sqlitedb');
$result = sqlite_array_query($dbhandle, 'SELECT * FROM users');
foreach ($result as $entry) {
    echo ...;
}
?>

 Но код 

<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('mysqlitedb.db');
    }
}
$db = new MyDB();
$result = $db->query('SELECT bar FROM foo');
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
?>

Я не понимаю.. А другого примера на сайте php посвящённому sqlite3 нету..

Comment: @istimbi, это не по sqlite надо читать, а по ООП. Это простая реализация тех же функций через объект.

Comment: Можете покидать ссылки?

Comment: @istimbi, если вы просите ссылки на основы ООП, то можно заняться изучением [официальной документации][1], начиная с "Основ" и далее по содержанию

 [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Я правильно понял что оба кода равнозначны? Просто реализованны по разному? И отличия в синтаксисе команд для работы с sqlite3 и более старых версии нет?

Comment: @istimbi, скорее всего различия есть, но не глобальные. Основная разница (для клиента, т.е. для вас) будет действительно в реализации. Просто в PHP никак не может отторгнуть функциональное программирование или хотя бы написать доки как по ФП, так и по ООП.